# target array by passing argument in function in js/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object to collect data to send to an API:

```
apiData: {
    colors: [],
    years: [],
    // ..
}
```

Many of the children of this `apiData` are arrays like `colors` and `years`, I call these 'subgroups'. A user can select a multitude of subgroups with checkboxes that trigger:

```
handleCheckboxColorChange(value, isChecked) {
    let newApiData = '';
    this.setState( (prevState) => {
        if (isChecked === true) {
            newApiData = {...prevState.apiData, colors: [...prevState.apiData.colors, value]}
        } else {
            newApiData = {...prevState.apiData, colors: [...prevState.apiData.colors.filter(item => item !== value)]
            }
        }
        return {apiData: newApiData}
    }, () => this.props.handleApiCall(this.state.apiData))
}
```

I use a similar function for the other 'subgroups'. For `years`, all that changes in the function is `colors` to `years`. So I wish to create a more general function that can take a 'subgroup' as argument to target the right array in my object. I tried to pass a third variable (a string) `subGroup` like so:

```
handleCheckboxChange(value, isChecked, subGroup) {
     // ..
     newApiData = {...prevState.apiData, subGroup: [...prevState.apiData.subGroup, value]}
```

This does not work (I guess because it is now looking for the child 'subgroup' in my object). How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) :

```
handleCheckboxChange(value, isChecked, subGroup) {
  // ..
  newApiData = {...prevState.apiData, [subGroup]: [...prevState.apiData[subGroup], value]}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it a bit prettier, you can use this:

```
handleCheckboxColorChange(value, isChecked, subGroup) {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
      const newState = { ...prevState }
      newState[subGroup] = isChecked ? [ ...newState[subGroup], value ] : newState[subGroup].filter(item => item !== value)
      return newState
  }, () => this.props.handleApiCall(this.state.apiData))
}
```